# Installing PostgreSQL Client v10 on AWS Amazon Linux (EC2) AMI

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have successfully launched new AWS RDS PostgreSQL *v10* instance and need to install PostgreSQL v10 client on Amazon Linux EC2 instance.

I have tried to install it with `yum`, but it cant find the package for v10:

```
[ec2-user@ip-X-X-X-X ~]$ sudo yum install -y postgresql10
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main      | 2.1 kB  00:00:00
amzn-updates  | 2.5 kB  00:00:00
No package postgresql110 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Previously I managed to install PostgreSQL client v9.5 with:

```
[ec2-user@ip-X-X-X-X ~]$ sudo yum install -y postgresql95
```

I guess I need to add Postgres yum repository, as mentioned in https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/. But what Platform should I choose for Amazon Linux? Red Hat?

Answer (score 252, accepted):

You can try to run the following command on your Linux server:

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install postgresql10
```

Comment: This seems to be with With "Amazon Linux 2" only

Comment: It should be the preferred solution if you are using Amazon Linux 2. Support is guaranteed.

Comment: Awesome, this was precisely what I needed for my amzn2 box. Much appreciated.

Comment: Did not work for me in an AmazonLinux 2 CodeBuild image. The CodeBuild images may be different than regular EC2 images.

Comment: More info on https://dailyscrawl.com/how-to-install-postgresql-on-amazon-linux-2/

Comment: works also with `postgresql11` and `postgresql12`

Comment: I get this error:

 sudo: amazon-linux-extras: command not found

Comment: This only works with Amazon Linux 2.

Comment: This always installs psql (PostgreSQL) 9.2.24, which throws - "psql: SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above"

Answer (score 61):

Packages/Repos which is designed to work of RedHat will work on Amazon Linux also, Amazon Linux is a minimal-install version of RHEL. You may run into compatibility issues if you select old version of Amazon Linux (Amazon linux 1) for the below steps, otherwise it should work fine in the latest version Amazon Linux 2.

**Check Amazon Linux version**

```
[ec2-user ~]$ cat /etc/system-release
Amazon Linux release 2.0 (2017.12) LTS Release Candidate
```

**Install RHEL 7 yum repo for PostgreSQL**

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo yum install -y  https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/10/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat10-10-2.noarch.rpm

[ec2-user ~]$ sudo sed -i "s/rhel-\$releasever-\$basearch/rhel-latest-x86_64/g" "/etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-10-redhat.repo"
```

**Install PostgreSQL Client v10**

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo yum install -y postgresql10
[ec2-user ~]$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 10.3
```

Read more about [Amazon Linux 2](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/)

**Note! Amazon Linux 2 provides additional package installation through [Amazon Linux Extras Repository](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/faqs/#Amazon_Linux_Extras_Repository) (`amazon-linux-extras`) ((client only)). Since postgresql10 is not yet available, adding extra yum repo is the only solution per today.**

**UDATE 2019May**

those who see

> Error: Package: pgdg-redhat-repo-42.0-4.noarch
>   (/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch)
>
> Requires: /etc/redhat-release

may still install step by step all dependencies and the server with:

```
yum install -y https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/10/redhat/rhel-latest-x86_64/postgresql10-libs-10.7-2PGDG.rhel7.x86_64.rpm
yum install -y https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/10/redhat/rhel-latest-x86_64/postgresql10-10.7-2PGDG.rhel7.x86_64.rpm
yum install -y https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/10/redhat/rhel-latest-x86_64/postgresql10-server-10.7-2PGDG.rhel7.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Thank you Ismar for making the content nice!!

Comment: Receiving `Error: Package: postgresql10-10.3-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64 (pgdg10) Requires: systemd-sysv` when executing `sudo yum install -y postgresql10`

Comment: Anon,This is because you are using the old version of Amazon linux(Amazon linux 1).Please use the current version (Amazon linux 2).Then you would be able to install.

Comment: I get the same error. My AMI version is "Amazon Linux AMI release 2018.03", which by the naming seems to be quite fresh. Is systemd removed from later versions of the AMI?

Comment: thanks for this. works perfectly (as of Jun 4, 2018) on Amazon Linux release 2 (2017.12)

Comment: seems amazon-linux-extras install an only client, not a server.

Comment: @anon58192932 When you get this error please do the following
$sudo yum update
$sudo yum install -y postgresql

Comment: The "May 2019 Update" to this post make this possible for me on Linux 2!  Thanks!

Comment: Receiving Error: Package: postgresql10-10.3-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64 (pgdg10) Requires: systemd-sysv when executing yum install -y https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/10/redhat/rhel-latest-x86_64/postgresql10-10.7-2PGDG.rhel7.x86_64.rpm

Comment: does not work on `Amazon Linux AMI release 2018.03`

Comment: UDATE 2019May helped me. I am working on Amazon Linux 2

Comment: the updated version for 2018 DOES WORK ... quite well by the way ! thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 21):

Since none of the previous answers worked for me, I'm adding a solution that let me install the postgresql10 client. We're using `VERSION="2018.03"` of Amazon Linux AMI in our pipelines.

Building from source:

<sup>Note: The link below points to postgresql 10.4, you may want to check for newer subversions</sup>

```
sudo yum install -y gcc readline-devel zlib-devel
wget https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v10.4/postgresql-10.4.tar.gz
tar -xf postgresql-10.4.tar.gz
cd postgresql-10.4
./configure
make -C src/bin
sudo make -C src/bin install
make -C src/include
sudo make -C src/include install
make -C src/interfaces
sudo make -C src/interfaces install
make -C doc
sudo make -C doc install
```

The new package should be installed with all its executables in here: `/usr/local/pgsql/bin`

Now, keep in mind that commands `psql`, `pg_dump` etc. still point to the old version of the psql client. You can run with the full executable paths (`/usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql`) or prepend the new directory at the beginning of your `$PATH` so that the system will look it up first:

Edit `~/.bash_profile` adding this at the end:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/pgsql/bin:$PATH"
```

Then run:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Now everything should be ready:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xx-x-x-xxx ~]$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 10.4
```

Comment: Based on postgres source install docs, I ended up tweaking the make steps to:
`./configure && make`, `sudo make install`, `echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/pgsql/bin' | sudo tee /etc/profile.d/postgres.sh`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked great for me. I did the same with postgresql-12.3

Answer (score 13):

Adapting Haneef Mohammed's answer for Amazon Linux 1 (tested on 2018.03):

Go to the Postgres [repositories page](https://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php) and grab the URL for 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64'. Install the PG repos and amend the entries, replacing '$releasever' with '6.9' (or [newer](https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/10/redhat/)?):

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo yum install -y  https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/10/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-redhat10-10-2.noarch.rpm

[ec2-user ~]$ sudo sed -i "s/rhel-\$releasever-\$basearch/rhel-6.9-x86_64/g" "/etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-10-redhat.repo"
```

Second part is the same:

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo yum install -y postgresql10
[ec2-user ~]$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 10.3
```

Comment: before 'yum install' you need to do > $yum clean all

Comment: Error: Package: pgdg-redhat-repo-42.0-5.noarch (/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch)
           Requires: /etc/redhat-release

Comment: It seems the pgdg repo is no longer available, so this answer doesn't work:
"Cannot open: https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/10/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-redhat10-10-2.noarch.rpm. Skipping."

Answer (score 11):

PGDG repo is no longer available for Amazon Linux. So you can use amazon repo.

```
amazon-linux-extras install postgresql10 vim epel -y
```

Or follow this article

https://installvirtual.com/install-postgresql-10-on-amazon-ec2/

Answer (score 8):

As of May 25th, 2019, the following direct RPM installation worked for me on Amazon Linux 1 2018.03 (latest Beanstalk platform version) to install PostgreSQL Client 10.7:

```
sudo rpm -ivh --force https://yum.postgresql.org/testing/10/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/postgresql10-libs-10.7-2PGDG.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh --force https://yum.postgresql.org/testing/10/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/postgresql10-10.7-2PGDG.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 8):

##### Solution for Amazon Linux release 2023 (Amazon Linux) instances

If you receive errors like:

- `No match for argument: postgresql10`
- `No match for argument: postgresql11`
- `No match for argument: postgresql14`

while running `sudo yum install -y postgresql<your_version>`

Just check what versions persist in repositories using `sudo yum search "postgres"`. In my case there were neither `postgresql10` nor `postgresql14`, but was `postgresql15`.

So I invoked `sudo yum install postgresql15` and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

PSql10.7 installation (08/20/2019)

Remove all of the older version Psql client and perform the below steps:

```
wget https://yum.postgresql.org/10/redhat/rhel-6.9-x86_64/postgresql10-libs-10.7-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
wget https://yum.postgresql.org/10/redhat/rhel-6.9-x86_64/postgresql10-10.7-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh postgresql10-libs-10.7-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh postgresql10-10.7-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 5):

The following works for psql v11 on Amazon Linux (v1)

```
wget https://yum.postgresql.org/11/redhat/rhel-6.9-x86_64/postgresql11-libs-11.8-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
wget https://yum.postgresql.org/11/redhat/rhel-6.9-x86_64/postgresql11-11.8-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64.rpm

sudo yum clean all
sudo rpm -ivh postgresql11-libs-11.8-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh postgresql11-11.8-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 4):

This my 2019 solution:

Just do

```
 sudo amazon-linux-extras install postgresql9.6
```

You should not have to download it from any outside source, since it is already given to you by default from Amazon, all you have to do is install it.

The other solutions didnt work for me and I spent a good amount time banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why.

And surprisingly even though you install psql9.6 you get version 10.

Comment: Assumes Amazon Linux 2, does not work for Amazon Linux instances

Answer (score 2):

The way I resolved the issue was by running

```
yum clean all
```

before

```
yum install -y postgresql10
```

on Amazon Linux

Comment: I would be very surprised if this was actually done on an Amazon Linux instance and not an Amazon Linux 2 instance.

Answer (score 1):

For Amazon Linux 2 and AWS Cloud Shell instance you might use commands like this:

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras | grep postgre # To see the available versions
sudo amazon-linux-extras install postgresql14 # To perform installation
```

Answer (score 0):

for v11 on Amazon Linux 2 I had to do

```
yum -y install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/11/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos11-11-2.noarch.rpm
sed -i "s/rhel-\$releasever-\$basearch/rhel-7-x86_64/g" "/etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-11-centos.repo"
```