# Connecting EC2 Amazon Linux2 to RDS PostgreSQL

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have an EC2 Amazon Linux2 running, and I want to access to RDS PostgreSQL databse from EC2.
I have finished adding EC2's security group ID to RDS's security group inbound.
I also successfully connected to RDS from my local PC.

I was looking for a way (or cli command) to connect to RDS from EC2 Amazon Linux.
Similary way for MySQL is:

```
sudo yum install mysql
mysql -u {username} -p -h {hostname}
```

I want to do the same with PostgreSQL, but could not find how to do so.
If there's a way I can follow through, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: See: [Installing PostgreSQL Client v10 on AWS Amazon Linux (EC2) AMI - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49573258/installing-postgresql-client-v10-on-aws-amazon-linux-ec2-ami)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you use `docker` for that?

The easiest and fastest way that comes into my head is to do something like that

#### First, install docker

```
$ curl -L get.docker.com | sudo bash
$ sudo usermod -a -G docker $(whoami)
```

... you need to logout & login!

#### Then run docker container

```
$ docker run --rm -it postgres psql -h [your_RDS_host] -U [username] -W [database_name]
```

And you should be fine